# Box-Cox transformation vs. predictor transformation in multiple linear regression

Tags: r, multiple-regression, data-transformation, normality-assumption, qq-plot

I first tried to transform my predictors one by one, but I couldn't find a satisfactory transformation. Then I tried Box-Cox which solved a lot of linearity and constant variance issues, but I still had a not-so-great QQ plot
[image]

The data set I'm using is http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality, and above is a scatter plot with chlorides as response (after Box-Cox) and alcohol as a predictor. This QQ plot pattern appeared every time that I used Box-Cox on chlorides with one predictor.

Thus, I decided to just Box-Cox the full model, and I think(?) I got a better QQ plot (less left skew I believe):
[image]

In my case, should I give up on transforming the predictors and just go with Box-Cox on the full model, or am I missing something? I am still a beginner to linear regression, so I may be making some mistakes here. My end-goal is to find the optimal model to predict chlorides.

Comment: The first one looks much better than the second. That is because the second one has heavier tails.

Comment: I was taught that a good QQ plot should be more or less a straight line. Isn't the second one straighter? Also, I thought the first one had more left skew as the left side of the plot is further from the line than in the second plot.

Comment: Sorry I misread that.  It is just a slight difference between them.

Comment: I would suggest stratifying your data, if possible.  Quite often these issues result from a lot of different populations being grouped together which each have their own central tendencies and spread.  Taken as a whole, they can be impossible to model, stratified, they tend to make sense.  For example, do you have information related to growing region, type of wine/grape?  I would suspect each would have their role ot play in the model.

Comment: Based on the information you added here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266905/what-would-you-do-with-the-following-qq-plot, try looking at your data one factor at a time.  Sometimes you will find that a factor which seems reasonable is actually bad for the whole model.  It may mean you are simply missing information that makes that variable meaningful or there is just too much noise in that factor.