# What would you do with the following QQ-plot?

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation, outliers, qq-plot

I'm using this data set: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality and regressing chlorides on nine predictors (all except residual sugar and quality). I have Box-Cox transformed the response and removed three potential outliers (which did nothing), and now I still have a QQ-plot with heavy tails.[image]

The data set comes from one place in Portugal using the same grapes (red wine only), so I can't really differentiate the data. Is there something that I can do?

Comment: You already asked this question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266070/box-cox-transformation-vs-predictor-transformation-in-multiple-linear-regressio  While the added information is useful, it would have been better if you updated your previous question with the new information.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your dataset, I would transform the **total sulfur dioxide** variable (see histogram below). It appears to be highly positively skewed and may be contributing to the heavy tails. The variable **free sulfur dioxide** may also benefit from a transformation.

Non-normality in the regressors can result in a similar problem in the residuals. [Hamilton (1992, 125)](http://www.worldcat.org/title/regression-with-graphics-a-second-course-in-applied-statistics/oclc/28758918) says "...if *e* has a substantially nonnormal distribution, transformations of one or more variables may help."

[image]